# ERROR: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a web application using Java Spring MVC. This web mostly will do CRUD function (Create-Read-Update-Delete).

Recently, I got this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from assignment where username=reza]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'reza' in 'where clause'
```

This is my DAO file:

```
    @Override
    public List < Assignment > showAllAssignment(String username) {
        String sql = "select * from assignment where username=" + username;
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new AssignmentMapper());
    }
```

This is my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/showAllAssignment/{reqUserName}/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView showAllAssignment(@PathVariable("reqUserName") String reqUserName) {
     List < Assignment > list = new ArrayList < Assignment > ();
     list = assignmentService.showAllAssignment(reqUserName);
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("show_All_Assignments");
     mav.addObject("assignment", list);
     return mav;
 }
```

Further error that I got:

```
2018-05-03 01:55:08,232 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.assignment.controller.AssignmentController.showAllAssignment(java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from assignment where username=reza]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'reza' in 'where clause'
2018-05-03 01:55:08,234 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.assignment.controller.AssignmentController.showAllAssignment(java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from assignment where username=reza]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'reza' in 'where clause'
2018-05-03 01:55:08,234 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.assignment.controller.AssignmentController.showAllAssignment(java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from assignment where username=reza]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'reza' in 'where clause'
2018-05-03 01:55:08,235 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]-[DEBUG] Could not complete request
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from assignment where username=reza]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'reza' in 'where clause'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    at org.assignment.dao.AssignmentDaoImpl.showAllAssignment(AssignmentDaoImpl.java:67)
    at org.assignment.service.AssignmentServiceImpl.showAllAssignment(AssignmentServiceImpl.java:39)
    at org.assignment.controller.AssignmentController.showAllAssignment(AssignmentController.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'reza' in 'where clause'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:433)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376)
    ... 42 more
```

The problem is I would like to select data inside my table assignment, where the username is define.

For example the `String username1 = 'reza';` But when I try to show all data using syntax in above `select * .... where username="+username1;`
The result, the system read the 'reza' as column not as the value on column.

Any one can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: how about a `;` at the end of the query?

Comment: you mean `String sql = "select * from assignment where username="+username; ` ?@Gewure

Comment: Is it possible username is expecting a `'` surrounding your `username`  (i.e. `"select * from assignment where username = '" + username + "'"`

Comment: @AgnesPalit yes, but more like: `String sql = "select * from assignment where username='"+username+"';"; `

Comment: on the console if i surrounding the `username` with `'` the syntax will be read as `2018-05-03 02:09:35,133 [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]-[DEBUG] Executing SQL query [select * from assignment where username='username']` , so it does not exactly get the value inside the variable username @JacobBlanton Any idea?

Comment: @Gewure Wow it works! Thank you very much. I want to put vote up in your comment but there is no feature to vote up in comment. But I really appreciated your help :D

Comment: @AgnesPalit I'll post it as answer so you can accept it :) You need 100 reputation to be able to upvote comments.

Comment: Okay, I will vote up once you answer @Gewure

Comment: This question should be deleted as not useful in anyway. Somebody forgot some quotes, not helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SQL query you provided wasn't proper SQL, as the error suggested:

try `String sql = "select * from assignment where username='"+username+"';";`

instead of `String sql = "select * from assignment where username="+username;`

Comment: I have check it 'green' your answer, but I still can not up vote, and i saw it because my reputation less than 15, I am sorry with that. But once my repotation more than 15, I will vote up you answer. Many thanks @Gewure

Comment: don't worry. glad i helped.

Answer (score 2):

You should use query parameter for username to have it correctly quoted AND SQL escaped... your concatenation is a potential SQL injection entry point if username comes from any external source (UI, ...) you don't fully control and will fail at first username containing a single quote if caller doesn't escape correctly.

Comment: Could you please give the clear example of syntax, to show what you mean?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

Comment: I see, but I am sorry that maybe your answer does not meet what I need to solve my real problem. Actually the previous answer by @Gewure already solve my problem and now it works well. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, solved it by commenting and uncommenting one of my dependencies which made my gradle file work properly.

Comment: how is this correlated to gradle? What dependency caused this outcome?